# How to improve the mongodb performance with single node with large dataset?

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query, nosql

I just started with mongodb. I am working with 38GB data set(68 million document) with ssd stoarge.
 But the performance is going done with indexing and without indexing also. And its using so much ram for simple find query with two fields, No cpu use.

Its taking 18 min to fetch 1.6 million records.  What are  the factor, which are helpful to improve mongodb performance with single node?

My Document looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55e7eec02756dd0f1e693b72"), 
  "categorieId" : 2, 
  "title" : "AntiMalware",  
  "messageValue" : " #\"Antimalware: \"Windows Defender\" is Not Updated and Running\"#",  
  "timestamp" : "8/19/2015 11:06:24 AM",  
  "resultStatusId" : 2,  
  "messageFormat" : "Text",  
  "titleId" : 1,  
  "resultStatus" : "Warning",  
  "antiMalwareName" : "Comodo Antivirus",  
  "categories" : "Security" }
```

My indexs are on `titleId` and `resultStatusId`.

My query is:

```
   db.collection.find({"titleId":21, resultStatusId:1})
```

The explain output is:

```
{
    "queryPlanner" : {
        "plannerVersion" : 1,
        "namespace" : "techHealLogAnalysis.techHealTestLogData",
        "indexFilterSet" : false,
        "parsedQuery" : {
            "$and" : [
                {
                    "resultStatusId" : {
                        "$eq" : 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "titleId" : {
                        "$eq" : 21
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "titleId" : 1,
                    "resultStatusId" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "titleId_1_resultStatusId_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "titleId" : [
                        "[21.0, 21.0]"
                    ],
                    "resultStatusId" : [
                        "[1.0, 1.0]"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
    },
    "executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 1671842,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 1108805,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 1671842,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 1671842,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "nReturned" : 1671842,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 177670,
            "works" : 2143234,
            "advanced" : 1671842,
            "needTime" : 0,
            "needFetch" : 471391,
            "saveState" : 471391,
            "restoreState" : 471391,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "docsExamined" : 1671842,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 1671842,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 1470,
                "works" : 1671843,
                "advanced" : 1671842,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needFetch" : 0,
                "saveState" : 471391,
                "restoreState" : 471391,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "titleId" : 1,
                    "resultStatusId" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "titleId_1_resultStatusId_1",
                "isMultiKey" : false,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "titleId" : [
                        "[21.0, 21.0]"
                    ],
                    "resultStatusId" : [
                        "[1.0, 1.0]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 1671842,
                "dupsTested" : 0,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0,
                "matchTested" : 0
            }
        }
    },
    "serverInfo" : {
        "host" : "instance-7",
        "port" : 27017,
        "version" : "3.0.6",
        "gitVersion" : "1ef45a23a4c5e3480ac919b28afcba3c615488f2"
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Large RAM usage for MongoDB is normal. It always uses as much RAM as available for caching recent results. To help you improve your querry, you would need to show us how your documents look, what indexes you have and what query you perform.

Comment: My Document looks like: -                                                                                { "_id" : ObjectId("55e7eec02756dd0f1e693b72"), "categorieId" : 2, "title" : "AntiMalware", "messageValue" : " #\"Antimalware: \"Windows Defender\" is Not Updated and Running\"#", "timestamp" : "8/19/2015 11:06:24 AM", "resultStatusId" : 2, "messageFormat" : "Text", "titleId" : 1, "resultStatus" : "Warning", "antiMalwareName" : "Comodo Antivirus", "categories" : "Security" }

Comment: My query is :- db.collection.find({"titleId":21, resultStatusId:1})                                            My indexs are on "titleId" and "resultStatusId"

Comment: Are these two separate indexes or is it a compound index? Please also [run the query with explain](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/cursor.explain/) and add the output to the question. It provides vital information about if and how your indexes are used.

Comment: its single compound index.

Answer (score 2):

Database systems with large data sets and high throughput applications can challenge the capacity of a single server. Larger data sets exceed the storage capacity of a single machine. Finally, working set sizes larger than the system’s RAM stress the I/O capacity of disk drives. Deploying sharding for your case may really be useful. Once check out the following link.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-introduction/

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you please tell me how to change the storage engine in mongodb? In my case i am using MMAPv1 but i want to use WiredTiger.

Comment: @user3835987 absolutely no idea. I'm a newbie around here. But Try learning deploying SHARDS and REPLICATION that will give u the total essence of using MongoDB